# Concatenating plots of rows of a matrix in a single plot - Python

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib

I would like to plot the rows of my matrix `M`, in a single plot, essentially concatenating the plots of the single rows in one single plot.

I know that, in order to plot a single row of a matrix, denoted by the index `j`, I could use:

```
T = range(M.shape[0])
plt.plot(T, M[j, :])
plt.show()
```

(obviously giving the value of `j`). But I can't figure out how I could use this (if this is to be used at all) to plot ALL the rows of my matrix in a single plot. This means that I will have my first row plotted and then, consecutively, the second row plotted on the right and so on until the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
row_len = M.shape[0]
for j in range(M.shape[1]):
    T = range(j*row_len, (j+1)*row_len)
    plt.plot(T, M[j, :])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get an error of "invalid syntax" in "for j in range(M.shape[1])"

Comment: add the `:` at the end of the `for`-loop line

Answer (score 1):

You can just flatten the Matrix `M`:

```
M_flattened = M.flatten() # same as M.reshape(M.size)
T = range(M.size)
plot(T, M_flattened)
plt.show()
```